# Is there a Java 1.5 varargs API for slf4j yet?

Tags: java, logging, variadic-functions, slf4j

I want to get rid of this lot...

```
public void info(String msg);
public void info(String format, Object arg);
public void info(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2);
public void info(String format, Object[] argArray);
```

...and replace it with this one...

```
public void info(String format, Object ... args);
```

...so that my logging syntax doesn't have to change depending on the number of arguments I want to log. There seems to be lots of discussion and work around it, but where is it? Or should I wrap the wrapper that is slf4j?

Comment: If an open-source project does not accept your patches, and you need the particular functionality, then the answer seems pretty obvious, no?

Comment: @kdgregory - no, not obvious & not how it should work; that's a commercial (fatalist) mindset, where software=vendor.pay().requestFeature().receiveUpgrade(); if catch UnsupportedException, it's new Vendor() || self.screwed(). But openSource=public.download().use().requestFeature().awaitUntil(public.getConsensus());  if consensus <= cost (in time or $$), it should be worth it. Much of my time (as commercial sw dev) is spent implementing poorly conceived enhancements motivated not by consensus/common sense, but dollars.received(). I'm also expected to maintain this.mess, adding to future costs.

Comment: @michael_n - not sure how you interpreted my comment, but the obvious answer is "make a fork." It's nice if the project maintainers want the same things you do, but it doesn't always happen.

Comment: @kdgregory sorry, I'm admittedly nit-picking (orig comment not meant to be taken too seriously). Just different opinion/perspective on "obvious" vs. last resort. Maybe 10-15 yrs ago "freedom" in opensource equated to forking. In practice, good projects were destroyed by forks; usually by personalities that refused to communicate. I'm simply advocating participation & consensus building as a strength of open-source (vs. PHB dictates @ the office), w/ forking as a last resort (though today, git & pull-requests make forks less tragic). Fwiw, the API now exists in slf4j, so I guess it's all moot.

Comment: @kdgregory and actually, as a minor practical addendum to my philosophical rantings, in my well-known mega-software company with a [legal department to rival the engineering department](http://www.bonkersworld.net/organizational-charts/) they wouldn't even let me modify the source (even if for internal use). It would never get approved, even for a two-character fix for an obvious, critical security flaw. I'd have to chuck the library, or find someone "on the outside" to make the fix & then get the newer version of the library approved (maybe 6-12 months of waiting for approvals (serious)).

Comment: @michael_n - Not a happy situation, I agree. I had the opposite experience, where my company maintained a fork of Hibernate for several years. Some of the patches that we made got rolled into the mainline, some of the bugs/features were fixed by other people, and some we had to preserve forever (such as one involving the handling of a zero-length VARCHAR by a widely-used DBMS, where Gavin and my coworker got into a tiff in the bug report -- as I recall, Gavin said that the behavior was brain-dead, as was anyone who cared about it; I think my coworker called Gavin brain-dead).

Answer (score 14):

The real question is "Why must a jdk < 5 be supported by this any longer"?  If you have an older version of java, then use the older API.  It's that simple.  Why not make this fit better into the current java world?  I mean, JDK 5 isn't even supported without a support contract from Sun/Oracle. Backward compatibility is a joke in this case.

Comment: Support depends ón the platform. IBM supports 1.4 ón their platforms.

Comment: Oh, and thee answer to "why must ..." is that Ceki, the slf4j benevolent dictator, wants it to be so.

Comment: I don't get it... why not make slf4j 2.x that is compatible with Java 5, and keep slf4j 1.x compatible with java 0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 11):

This is finally solved. SLF4J 1.7.0 now required JDK 1.5 and has backward-compatible varargs methods.

Answer (score 7):

No.

The issue is still open how to do it right while still maintaining 100% backwards compatibility.

Feel free to see the discussion at http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
package util;

public class Util {
  public static Object[] va(Object... args) {
    return args;
  }
}

package foo;
import static util.Util.va;
...
 logger.info("a {}, b {}, c c {}", va("A", "B", "C"));
...
```

you can use va() in other places too.

Answer (score 4):

From reading the SLF4J javadoc for [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) the simple answer would appear to be no. From what I have read they want to stay compatible with older versions of the JDK.

If you are not really tied to using SLF4J then maybe [log5j](http://code.google.com/p/log5j/) is an option?

Comment: No, they want to stay binary compatible with older verdions of slf4j.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution of using varargs with SLF4J.

There is an open source project called Lumberjack that extends SLF4J to provides varargs logging methods. The extension is very natural, you don't feel any difference compared to using SLF4J (this is because Lumberjack is only a wrapper around SLF4J, so all the functionality is still provided by SLF4J).

Example usage:

```
JackLogger logger = JackLoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(Weather.class));

logger.info("Hello {}! The current time is {}:{}:{}, and after {} hours the weather will be {}.", "Jack", 13, 30, 0, 5, "sunny");
```

Lumberjack website: https://github.com/bogdanu/lumberjack

The Lumberjack license is the same as SLF4J's license, the MIT license, so there is no additional licensing restriction.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of Lumberjack*

Answer (score 0):

Try [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log) toolkit, which wraps SLF4J logging with a conveninent vararg interface.