# Java Logging statement says Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, slf4j

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Updater.class);
```

I am using `SLF4J` and `Logback`

When I try to log statements

```
LOGGER.info("{}:{}:{}", one, two, three)
```

it says

```
cannot find symbol method info(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

Is there not any way I can log more than two variables in a single `info` statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must upgrade SLF4J to 1.7 which includes [`Logger.info(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) varargs method. See [Bug 31 - Varargs for Logger methods](http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31) fixed after six years worth of discussion.

Prior to 1.7 you must surround arguments with `Object[]` if you are using more than two:

```
LOGGER.info("{}:{}:{}", new Object[] {one, two, three})
```

## See also

- [Is there a Java 1.5 varargs API for slf4j yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952947)

Comment: Maven repository seems to have `1.6.6` as latest http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an old version of slf4j.

In previous version you could only log up to 2 parameters in this way, but newer version can take [any number of parameters](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 0):

As per [JavaDoc](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) of Logger, you can use either of the following,

```
  void  info(String format, Object... arguments)
  void  info(String format, Object arg)
  void  info(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2)
```